# Programmatically detect panelizer columns layout

Tags: panels

Can you give me some directions how to properly detect the panelizer current layout. My idea is when one pane is added to the page to programmatically detect is it 1, 2 or 3 columns wide and based on this information to switch between different cases and to show content with different settings. I tried to locate this information using [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module  but nothing useful came up.